# glyphicon button as audio_tag control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, button, audio

I've consulted the audio_tag [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/audio_tag) to implement an audio feature in one of my views to both play a file upon loading the page, and then to play again through a control. The feature currently works, by pulling the audio file from the Word model:

```
<%= audio_tag current_word.sound, autoplay: true, controls: true %>
```

I'm interested in having a glyphicon button replace the default scroller/volume control that audio_tag produces (I'm anticipating audio files to be a couple second longs on average, so scrolling through the audio file or adjusting volume won't be necessary).

Is there a way I can combine the above audio_tag with following button for a single-click play option?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

I've been looking at this [blog](https://howilearnedrails.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/play-audio-file-on-button-click-in-rails/) post on the topic, though I'm not sure where in the app to place the js in order to apply the analogous solution with a glyphicon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<%= audio_tag current_word.sound, class: "audio-play" %>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg", id="audioButton">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button> #Add id audioButton for js purpose
```

in your app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#audioButton").on("click", function() {
        $(".audio-play")[0].currentTime = 0;
        return $(".audio-play")[0].play();
      });
});
```

Comment: This works when I reload the page, but if I click away and come back through the menu the button stops playing the audio. Is there something that can be added to the jQuery to make the click-play available always?

Comment: Do you mean you want to play the audio no matter which page you navigate to? Or you want the audio to continue once you come back to the page?

Comment: Just for the button functionality to still be available if I leave and come back to the page. (There is no response to clicking if I navigate away and come back through clicking the navbar).

Comment: To follow up, it was a matter of dealing with turbolinks. The button now works as intended :)