# Only top audio_tag button plays

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, audio

I'm starting out with audio on my site; I've [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605530/glyphicon-button-as-audio-tag-control) implemented an audio_tag with a glyph button in one of my views. In a different view, I'm trying to list all of my word objects, and I would like to have a button to play each of their associated audio. As of now, this functionality only works for the very first word object listed in this view. How can I make the buttons play the sound upon click for all of the objects in the view?

Lesson show view:

```
<div class ="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
  <h3>Vocabulary</h3>
  <br>
  <ul>
    <% @lesson.words.each do |word| %>
      <li> 
        <%= image_tag word.image_url(:thumb) if word.image? %> 

        <b><%= word.term %></b> 

        <%= audio_tag word.sound, class: "audio-play" %>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default", id="audioButton">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>

        <i>(<%= word.reference %>)</i>

      </li>
      <br>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#audioButton").on("click", function() {
        $(".audio-play")[0].currentTime = 0;
        return $(".audio-play")[0].play();
      });
});
```

Comment: Give each one it's own unique id. in html ids must be unique. eg `"#audioButton1"` `"#audioButton2"` etc... alternatively, don't use ids, use class names eg `class="btn btn-default audio-button"` then `$(".audio-button").on("click", function()`

Comment: That solved it, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each one it's own unique id.

In html ids must be unique. eg "#audioButton1" "#audioButton2" etc... alternatively, don't use ids, use class names eg `class="btn btn-default audio-button"` then `$(".audio-button").on("click", function()`