# audio_tag plays same file for different buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, audio

I'm new at using audio_tag; I'm trying to use a set of buttons to play short audio files. I'm going off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801481/only-top-audio-tag-button-plays) post to implement this feature. I currently have two audio tags with associated buttons, which should play different files. However, both buttons play the first audio file. I'm assigning different IDs to each button, but this is not helping. If I remove the first file, then the second button plays the expected file. (The mp3 files are located in /public/audios).

How can I go about associating the correct file to its button?

view:

```
<%= audio_tag "a.mp3", class: "audio-play" %>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg", id="audioButtonA">A</button>

<br>

<%= audio_tag "e.mp3", class: "audio-play" %>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg", id="audioButtonE">E</button>
```

application.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#audioButtonA").on("click", function() {
        $(".audio-play")[0].currentTime = 0;
        return $(".audio-play")[0].play();
      });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#audioButtonE").on("click", function() {
        $(".audio-play")[0].currentTime = 0;
        return $(".audio-play")[0].play();
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `$(".audio-play")[0].play()` you are always selecting the same element with the file (`a.mp3`), generally the first element with the class `audio-play`. To achieve your aim, on button click you have to select the previous element wich is an audio tag like so:

```
$("#audioButtonE").on("click", function() {
    var audio = $(this).prev()[0];
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    return audio.play();
});
```