# audio_tag plays only the first listed audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, audio

I'm working with audio_tag in an index view: I want to make each of the word's corresponding sound file to be accessible through a button click. As of right now, all buttons play the sound corresponding to the first listed word. I've been trying to generalize the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175098/audio-tag-plays-same-file-for-different-buttons) post to this situation, but I'm lost as to how to generalize the effect in the context of listing the sound files from the model. How can I make the button play the sound associated with each specific item?

View:

```
<ul>
  <% @lesson.words.each do |word| %>
    <li> 
      <%= image_tag word.image_url(:thumb) if word.image? %> &nbsp        
        <b><%= word.term %></b>

        <%= audio_tag word.sound, class: "audio-play" %>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default audio-button">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button> 

    </li>
    <br>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

application.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$(".audio-button").on("click", function() {
  $(".audio-play")[0].currentTime = 0;
    return $(".audio-play")[0].play();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, `$(".audio-play")[0]` will return the 1st audio tag in the whole page, that's why the audio of the 1st listed word is always played.

Update your script as follows

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".audio-button").on("click", function() {
    var audio = $(this).prev(".audio-play");

    audio.currentTime = 0;
    return audio.play();
  });
});
```

In the updated script, the audio tag right next to the button being clicked is retrieved and the corresponding sound will be played.

Run the [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/buithehoa/7jc4vhh1/)

Comment: The buttons don't play any audio with this updated script. Any ideas as to what else I could try? Thanks for the help--newbie here :)

Comment: @gonzalo2000 I've just updated my answer. You can run my sample code which is created based on your view code.

Comment: Thank you. I still lose the button functionality for all words with the updated script. The page otherwise displays as expected and I don't see an error in the logs.

Comment: In my example, I provided some HTML so you can compare yours with mine. If the structure of your HTML is similar to mine, it will work. What's the generated HTML of your page?

Comment: I see what my problem was, the return needed the [0], thus `return audio[0].play();` (as shown in your fiddle :)